# Is it possible to print a certain string base on LocalDateTime in java?

Tags: java, localtime, localdatetime

So i use localdatetime to get current time . I want it to print "Good night" when it is morning and "Good night" if it night base on localdatetime . I did find about isBefore() . I also did find some example but it is for date . I need some example .I am sorry if my question is not clear .

```
LocalDateTime localDate = LocalDateTime.now();
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM YYYY , h:mm a");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Basically your write simple java code for say good morning and good night based on time right?@Progman

Comment: actually i write code for Budget Tracker for my assignment . I just want to add this feature if possible .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **localDate.getHour()** to get current hour of day and use hour to print greeting message. Check below code -

```
private void printGrretingMessage()
{
    LocalDateTime currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    int hour = currentDateTime.getHour();

    if ( hour < 10 ) {
        System.out.println( "Good Morning" );
    } else if ( hour < 16 ) {
        System.out.println( "Good Afternoon" );
    } else if ( hour < 20 ) {
        System.out.println( "Good Evening" );
    } else {
        System.out.println( "Good Night" );
    }
}
```

I hope this works for you. :-)

Comment: thank u , currentDateTime.getHour(); this thing make it easier for me .I did managed solve it a min ago .But i need to make it like this .
  LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.parse("19:00:00");
  LocalTime time2 = LocalTime.parse("00:00:00");
  LocalTime time3 = LocalTime.parse("06:00:00");
  LocalTime time4 = LocalTime.parse("12:00:00");

Comment: Then you can get hour, minute and seconds separately and pass them to your parse function. e.g. currentDateTime.getHour() + ":" + currentDateTime.getMinute() + ":" + currentDateTime.getSecond().  Anyways this will complicate logic more.